# webpack module resolution depends on entry or chunk name

Tags: webpack, resolve, chunks, ab-testing, entry-point

I have rather big web application (approximately hundred modules with stores, thousand components and subcomponents).
Everything was good while ab-tests were simple - one module per condition, if-else statements, *webpack* chunks sometimes.

But now the business wants whole application a-b-c-d-tests and changes on the same test condition. And constant conditions for those tests in different places of different modules for some user groups...
The best solution seems to store changed modules files in different modules directories and switch directories while building.

It is impossible to do different *resolve.modules* routes for entry/chunks in the same config, is not it? So we need a lot of different configs, very long project building, a lot of repeating code in builds and swarm of builds growing as factorial ...
Yes, i can separate main common modules and libs with commonChunk plugin, but others will not automatically be separated.

Or I could use OOP pattern for changed modules - extend some parent, pass imported extended sumbodules and templates to children as arguments and so on -no routes required. We have one user form designed like this with 5 a-b-tests and variants - unsupported code is the result, hell of debugging and supporting...

I thought about relative paths first. Ok, a lot of "if" everywhere to target parent module, but no useless OOP  chains. But if we want to override several files in different levels of the module, for example, the root module template and sub-component style without change sub-component template the result will be with default sub-component style, not from ab-test directory.

I think the best solution for this problem would be the ability to make some condition for *resolve.modules* route depends on chunk (or entry), may be like this:

```
webpackConfig.resolve.modules: function (route, chunk, entry) {
    const modules = {
        newUser: 'newbie_modules_dir_path',
        payedUser: 'payed_modules_dir_path',
    }
    return modules [chunk || Entry] || 'default_modules_dir_path';
}
```

If *webpack* cannot do something like this with some other way, maybe I should write a plugin? Is it possible?

Or my problem is in directories structure and relative requires routes will be good with all relative paths and one level modules and components directories (without modules submcomponents, any directories inside modules and components are for ab-test changed files only)?
How to make routes priority when there are different ab-tests on the same module in the same time?

Now directories are like this:
`├── components
│   └── commonComponent
│       ├── CommonComponent.jsx
│       └── styles
│           └── CommonComponent.scss
└── modules
    └── moduleOne
        ├── components
        │   └── moduleOneComponent
        │       ├── ModuleOneComponent.jsx
        │       └── styles
        │           └── ModuleOneComponent.scss
        ├── models
        │   └── ModuleOneModel.js
        ├── ModuleOne.jsx
        └── styles
            └── ModuleOne.scss`

And I can't override *ModuleOneComponent.scss* without new entry with new routes like this:
`└── modules
    └── moduleTwo
        └── components
            └── moduleOneComponent
                └── styles
                    └── ModuleOneComponent.scss`

Any ideas?

Comment: I fear webpack might not be flexible enough at `resolve.modules` for this. What you can do however, is to use `require.context` and then [combine the contexts](https://survivejs.com/webpack/techniques/dynamic-loading/#combining-multiple-require-context-s). Maybe that gets close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

https://github.com/TrySound has answered to me yesterday too.
He said there is a reason to use custom loader replacing loaded content if path is matched. Need some more time to try all solutions...

Comment: Maybe https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/ is useful for inspiration.